# Adding closure to select raw queries (sum)

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have many different combinations of select sum from the same table but with slightly different where queries.

```
foreach ($transactionTypes as $type) {

   switch($type) {
      case 'Fuel':
          $values = \DB::table("transactions")
                 ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(fuel_charge) as fuel_charges"))
                 ->whereIn('type', ["Charge", "Refund"])
                 ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString())
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get();
      break;

      case 'Commission':
           $userIdsToBeUsed = $userIds->merge($tier3Ids);      

           $values = \DB::table("transactions")
                 ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(commission_charge) as commission_charges"))
                 ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString())
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get();

           break;
   }
}
```

As you can see, they are slightly different and I have a dozen of cases in the loop; but with this approach, I need to do a dozen queries to the same table.

What I want to ask is, Is there a way to combine them into a single query?

Something like:

```
$values = \DB::table("transactions")
            ->select(
              [ 
                 \DB::raw("user_id, SUM(fuel_charge) as fuel_charges") => function($q) {
                   // $q->where(...)
                 }
              ],
              [
                 \DB::raw("user_id, SUM(commission_charge) as commission_charges") => function($q) {
                    // $q->where(...);
                 }
              ])
            ->get()
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick thought. This can be a pretty neat hack you can say:

```
$userIdsToBeUsed = $userIds->merge($tier3Ids);
foreach ($transactionTypes as $type) {
          $values = \DB::table("transactions")
                 ->select(\DB::raw("user_id, SUM(" . strtolower($type) . "_charge) as " . strtolower($type) . "_charges"))
                 ->whereIn('type', ["Charge", "Refund"])
                 ->whereIn('user_id', $userIdsToBeUsed)
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $fromDate->toDateString())
                 ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $toDate->toDateString())
                 ->groupBy('user_id')
                 ->get();
}
```

I just use the lowercase of `$type` in query

Comment: How does this combine 10 separate queries into 1 query? My question was about database transactions, not making the code less lines